# Mono WinForms TableLayoutPanel cell locked in place relative to the form

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I have a form with a `TableLayoutPanel` on it, with controls in the cells. One of the controls is misbehaving, though, when I run my program in Mono. When I resize the form, the control just sits where it is, instead of moving to keep up with the rest of the controls in the `TableLayoutPanel`! This doesn't happen when I run my program in .NET. Does anyone have a clue what could cause my control to get stuck like this?

Comment: Was there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if it is only one of the controls that is misbehaving then the first guess is that the `anchor` or `dock` properties of that control isn't as the others. also it might just be that the control is behaving as it should and you just expected different behavior.

Comment: The behavior is different between .NET and Mono, so unless Mono is right and .NET is wrong, I don't think expecting wrong behavior is the problem. I tried setting the dock to fill (I think previously I had the anchor set to all directions) but it didn't change anything.